# HC - SR04 raspberry pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I have raspberry pi b and I am trying to write code in C that will allow me to use the [HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Ranging Module](http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf). I used the bcm2835 library to control the GPIO pins. I have connected it according to [this website](http://www.bytecreation.com/blog/2013/10/13/raspberry-pi-ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04). Here is my attempt:

```
# include <bcm2835.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

# define ECHO RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_03
# define TRIG RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_05

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
if (!bcm2835_init())
    return 1;

bcm2835_gpio_fsel(ECHO, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);
bcm2835_gpio_fsel(TRIG, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);

time_t clockstart = 0;
time_t clockstop = 0;

bcm2835_gpio_write(ECHO, LOW);
delay(2);

printf("trigger\n");

bcm2835_gpio_write(TRIG, HIGH);
usleep(10);
bcm2835_gpio_write(TRIG, LOW);

printf("measure\n");


while (bcm2835_gpio_lev(ECHO) == 0) {
    clockstart = time(NULL);
}

printf("B: %i\n", (int)clockstart);

while (bcm2835_gpio_lev(ECHO) == 1) {
    clockstop = time(NULL);
}

printf("E: %i\n", (int)clockstop);

time_t delta = clockstop - clockstart;

printf("D: %i\n", delta);

double distance = (delta * 340) / 2;

printf("DISTANCE: %i\n", distance);

bcm2835_close();
return 0;
}
```

Two problems exist:

1. My method for reading time is accurate only up to 1 sec,- however as I looked for a better way of doing this I found two methods and no definitive answer which one is actually better (clock_gettime() or gettimeofday()).
2. Even when pointed very far away, the loops finish almost instantaneously leading to the exact same value of both time() calls. This could be due to my crappy method of getting current time, but I"m not sure.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I need help finding it.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  here are some of the problems.  1) usleep() requires the  #include <unistd.h> (or similar) header file  2) this statement: 'printf("D: %i\n", delta);' is expecting a 'int' argument but argument 2 is 'time_t'   3) this statement: 'printf("DISTANCE: %i\n", distance);' is expecting a 'int' argument but the argument 2 is 'double'

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  here are some more problems:. 1) main parameter 'argc' is not used  2) main parameter 'argv[]' is not used.  Suggest declaring main via: 'int main( void )'

Comment: to get accurate (or at least more accurate) timing, 1) use interrupts, driven by the echo pin.  2) use gettimeofday() just before transmit and in interrupt handler function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** A better solution would be to use GPIO interrupts to time the echo interval

One suggestion (must really be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation)

Use gettimeofday() instead of time() -- it provides a greater resolution in timing.

Also, I'd change the while loops this way:

```
struct timeval start, end;

while (!bcm2835_gpio_lev(ECHO));   // Although gcc may be smart
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);        // enough to do this optimisation
while (bcm2835_gpio_lev(ECHO));    // on its own
gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

double delta = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0;     // s to ms
       delta += (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000.0;  // us to ms

printf("D: %f ms\n", delta);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tutorial I made on my blog, to get values from the HC-SR04 in C++ on Raspberry Pi!

You may want to take a look at it:

**https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/04/15/hc-sr04-raspberry-pi-c/**

At the end it look like this:

```
Sonar sonar;
sonar.init(trigger, echo);

while(1){
    cout << "Distance is " << sonar.distance(30000) << " cm." << endl; // 30000 is a timeout in microseconds
}
```